# Python Requests POST not working

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, python-requests

I am using python requests module for calling API's.
Everything was working fine until I pushed my code to AWS. Even on AWS it is working if I am working on dev server i.e., `ec2.####.amazon.com:8000` .

Here is my code :

```
r = requests.post(api_url, data = {"var 1":"value", "var 2":"value"})
```

My API url not allowed `GET` method so in response I am getting error that `GET` method not allowed which means `requests.post` is reads as `get`

Any idea what’s wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried accessing your rest of the project without port 8000(django's production env mode), also you can try commenting your request.method check and see if request to your API is working or not working at all.Cheers!

Comment: @JatinBansal yes it is working without 8000 and only post is giving error get is working fine

Comment: Can you try any of the REST clients for testing your POST requests, there are number of them available, like Advanced rest client for Google Chrome. Also please post some of the django debug info you get when error occurs (set debug to True).

Comment: on your localhost is your code working fine GET & POST.

Comment: @JatinBansal yes , I have posted the answer myself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the issue was due to SSL , if your server is using `https` method then you need to add following line in `requests.post`

```
r = requests.post(api_url, data = {"var 1":"value", "var 2":"value"}, verify=True)
```

Also make sure your api_url includes `https` not `http`

I have written a small function for that

```
def get_base_url(request):
    host = get_host(request)
    if request.is_secure():
        return '{0}{1}/{2}'.format('https://', host, 'url')
    else:
        return '{0}{1}/{2}'.format('http://', host, 'url')
```